# Python:2.7:NameError: name 'data' is not defined

Tags: python

I have python main python script, that imports functions from another python file, I get this error when it reaches the function `int_brief(data)`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "test.py", line 28, in <module>
        int_brief(data)
    NameError: name 'data' is not defined
```

The below function is being called in the main python file and it is imported from another python file that has the fucntions. Platform is Linux and Python 2.7, all the code that runs till the line that has variable `data` is working fine:

```
def int_brief(data):

    commandOutput = commandStatus('show ip int brief',expect_string=r'#')
    shellOut = redirect_shell()
    data = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(commandOutput),  widths=[23, 16, 4, 7, 22, 8])  
    return commandOutput, shellOut, data
```

I have tried to run the code without the parameter `data` in the function `int_brief()`, but still the error is thrown

Comment: you need to define what is `data` before passing it into function

Comment: The problem is at the place where you are calling `int_brief(data)`, not with the definition.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the function does not need the `data` parameter at all, as it is created within the function. Try removing the parameter, and then call the function with no parameter:

```
def int_brief():
    commandOutput = commandStatus('show ip int brief',expect_string=r'#')
    shellOut = redirect_shell()
    data = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(commandOutput),  widths=[23, 16, 4, 7, 22, 8])  
    return commandOutput, shellOut, data

stuff = int_brief()
```

If for some reason you can not change the `int_brief` function, you could just as well just pass *anything* as the `data` parameter, as it is never used before it is assigned a new value:

```
stuff = int_brief("does not matter, never used")
```